# Where can i find the (Index) folder

Tags: php, html, wordpress, google-chrome

need help finding this (index) folder that Google Chrome is showing me. I can't find the elements I highlighted in red.

I want to change the text via Sublime but can't find the exact folder the text is in.

Should be pretty simple for you guys, but I'm just a designer...

Picture of the problem:

[image]

Comment: go to where your template is located

Answer (score 0):

That's in the database, comes from the function `the_content()` in a page template, you just need to go to the page/post and remove the content and hit save.

You can generally tell it's coming from the Gutenberg editor when they have `wp-block-` class names and such.

Comment: p.s. you left the site url in the image above where you red circled, rest are removed.

Comment: I'm using WordPress. Can you maybe dumb it down for me, because I don't understand where to find it.

Comment: If you have the admin bar enabled there will be an edit post or an edit page button on it, you can press that and it will open the editor. You're using Elementor so there will be an edit with Elementor button I would imagine too. I'm 95% sure it's in the WordPress side of things and not Elementor though.

Comment: webdesign.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=13&action=edit

Comment: Thats the link you need for the page edit.... just fill in the first 4 letters of the url you blurred out.

Comment: Ah yes, but I wanted to learn how to change it without Elementor. So change the direct code.

Comment: Can you help me find the exact folder I need to edit? Since Google Chrome isn't showing anything.

Comment: Ok, page templates are in your theme directory, if you have access via FTP you would go `public_html/wp-content/themes/your-theme` or use the Theme Editor in the appearance tab on the back-end of WordPress. If that's the homepage then it can be one of the following `home.php` `index.php` `page.php`

Comment: I found the index.php folder, but that text is not inside it. I also check all the other folders in my Theme folder and none of them have that text inside them.

Comment: The text comes from `<?php the_content(); ?>` which is the function used to get the HMTL content from the database.

Comment: GOT IT! I checked the database and there it was. I changed it, and overwrote the old database with the new one. And it worked. Thanks!